# Sidekiq ignoring queues with pushed jobs

Tags: heroku, background-process, sidekiq

I'm pushing jobs like this:

`Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => StripeDataWorker, 'args' => [account.id, 'w', 'BalanceTransaction'], 'queue' => 'w')`

But they just sit in `Enqueued` and never get processed:

[image]

This happens to be on Heroku. I've restarted sidekiq many times and other jobs on other non-pushed queues are running without issue.

Here is my sidekiq.yml file:

```
:concurrency: 28
:queues:
  - [fast, 10]
  - [default, 5]
  - [slow, 1]
  - [generate, 2]
  - [a, 3]
  - [b, 3]
  - [c, 3]
  - [d, 3]
  - [e, 3]
  - [f, 3]
  - [g, 3]
  - [h, 3]
  - [i, 3]
  - [j, 3]
  - [k, 3]
  - [l, 3]
  - [m, 3]
  - [n, 3]
  - [o, 3]
  - [p, 3]
  - [q, 3]
  - [r, 3]
  - [s, 3]
  - [t, 3]
  - [u, 3]
  - [v, 3]
  - [w, 3]
  - [x, 3]
  - [y, 3]
  - [z, 3]
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I've also got a single queue that Sidekiq is ignoring, but things are processing normally from my other queues.